# SVN (Subversion) Problem "File is scheduled for addition, but is missing" - Using Versions

Tags: svn, macos, versions

I'm using Versions for SVN.

I attempt to commit and get this message:

> Commit failed (details follow):
>   '/Users/mike/Sites/mysite.com/astss-cvsdude/Trunk/cart/flashfile.swf'
>   is scheduled for addition, but is
>   missing

I suppose this is because I had added files to the repo, and then deleted them via the filesystem.

I'd like to have it simply make note of my change, and apply the change to the repo.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 128):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do: If you added the file via

```
svn add myfile
```

you only told svn to put this file into your repository *when you do your next commit*. There's no change to the repository before you type an

```
svn commit
```

If you delete the file before the commit, `svn` has it in its records (because you added it) but cannot send it to the repository because the file no longer exist.

So either you want to save the file in the repository and then delete it from your working copy: In this case try to get your file back (from the trash?), do the commit and delete the file afterwards via

```
svn delete myfile
svn commit
```

If you want to undo the `add` and just throw the file away, you can to an

```
svn revert myfile
```

which tells `svn` (in this case) to undo the add-Operation.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I wasn't aware that you're using the "Versions" GUI client for Max OSX. So either try a revert on the containing directory using the GUI or jump into the cold water and fire up your hidden Mac command shell :-) (it's called "Terminal" in the german OSX, no idea how to bring it up in the english version...)

Comment: The problem here is that he uses a GUI. If he can use the command-line anyway, he could just `svn rm` the file even if it doesn't exist in the directory.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware of the "Versions" client for OSX. He should be able to use "revert" anyway, shouldn't he? That would work with TortoiseSVN on Windows.

Comment: svn cleanups and svn rms later... Thanks for your help guys. Is there a way to tell svn, "look, I added some files via my OS's default file manager, and right now, the stuff in this folder, is what I want the current state of this repo to be... now let it happen... don't tell me what I can and can't do with these files, but yes, keep track of it all for me."?

Comment: An `svn add *` automatically adds all new, unversioned files, an `svn commit` immediately saves these changes to the repository. Afaik there is no aequivalent operation for removal, so if you remove files, you have to call `svn rm` manually.

Comment: Just FYI, I also had this problem and `svn rm`, even with `--force` does not work - it says `does not exist`. So `svn revert` is the correct thing to do here.

Comment: its same in english too. "Terminal" :)

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem with Versions displaying the same message. I simply right clicked the offending files and selected 'Revert...' from the right-click menu and all was good.

Basically Versions (actually Subversion) thinks you still want to add the file, but it cannot find it because you deleted it in the file system. The Revert option tells Subversion to forget about adding it.

Comment: I was getting this error because I had deleted a folder from the app hierarchy. I just added empty folder with the same name and it worked.

Answer (score 9):

Adding a file, and then deleting it is the kind of operation that's considered an error - and so SVN is telling you. You told it to expect some file data and then don't supply it when you commit, the red lights flash and the sirens go off!

The answer is to undo your add, alternatively commit the file and then use 'svn rm' to remove it from the filesystem and the repo.

Comment: I get this from Xcode where I add a file and did it wrong or something and tell Xcode to delete (move to trash).  Unfortunately Xcode leaves it in this state and does not do the rm from svn for me though it does delete the file...

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19375167/4820510) solved my similar problem. I used it to revert the changes, then I added everything and commited changes in the terminal with

```
svn add folder_path/*
svn commit -m "message"
```

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using Xcode to rename files in a folder reference. If you rename a file using Xcode, it will be marked for commit. If you later delete it before the commit, you will end up with this error.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the file from within VS, then from 'Repository Explorer', I copied the file to the working copy.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using TortoiseSVN…

From your commit window in the “Changes Made” section you can select all the offending files, then right-click and select delete.  Finish the commit and the files will be removed from the scheduled additions.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had run `svn add folder` and it added all the children too. Then I modified my `~/.subversion/config` and tried to commit again, which caused this error. Running `svn rm --keep-local folder/foo` on the file in the error message removes the file from tracking without deleting locally.