# Revert svn files by file pattern

Tags: bash, svn, revert

I'm trying to find a command (can be bash command) to revert a group of svn files.

Let's say I have some changes in my check-out and I run `svn st` and get this output:

```
My-MacBook-2:trunk aetzioni$ svn st
M    SomeFolderA/src/main/java/com/mycompany/package/classA.java
M    SomeFolderA/main/java/com/mycompany/package/classB.java
M    SomeFolderB/src/main/java/com/mycompany/package/classC.java
```

Now I want to find a command that does `svn revert` on all the files under `SomeFolderA`.

I tried something like this:

```
svn st | grep SomeFolderA | svn revert
```

But got this error message:

```
svn: Try 'svn help' for more info
svn: Not enough arguments provided
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I finally did it is by creating this command:

```
svn st | grep SomeFolderA | awk {'print $2'} | xargs svn revert
```

Explanation:

1. `svn st` - Finds all the modified file
2. `grep SomeFolderA` - Filters the svn output to only show lines that have `SomeFolderA`
3. `awk {'print $2'}` - removes the `M` at the beginning of each output line
4. `xargs svn revert` - The `xargs` command uses the output from previous command and passes it, as is, to the `svn revert` command