# svn move failed. Now move leads to error: Path already exists

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

I tried to move folder A, which is inside my working copy to another folder B inside the same working copy. The move failed because a file was used by a popular scientific calculation program.

Now it's not possible anymore to move folder A to folder B, because of the error `Path '...' already exists`.

Update and Clean-up didn't help.

When I try to commit the folder B, the folder 
A which should have been moved and all its files are marked `missing`.

Possible solutions:

- Use the Repo browser to move folder A to folder B.
- Commit and mark the missing folder A and its files.
- [Create folder named A in B and put it to ignore list. Commit.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1177655/2678563)
- Last resort: checkout everything to a new folder and try again.

How can I move Folder A to folder B, now that this error exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reverted the change according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2247972/2678563) and it worked fine afterwards.

Including that missing file as suggested by Simon F didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me. I Committed the folder and checked/included that "missing" file. (Tortoise)SVN "Deleted" the "missing" file (from the place where it was never really moved to) and then after that it was fine. I SVN-moved my file to its proper home.